# Clear Calendar Api not working

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I was using Google calendar Clear api but nowadays I am getting following error while clearing the calendar using calendar id.

I need to clear the calendar using calendar id. I tried the same api using following url as well and getting the same error.

Calendar Id: h9tbr9nlks0p8nrkjsgbrphci4@group.calendar.google.com

I am getting following error on every calendar.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear

message:Cannot clear primary calendar.

Comment: Same for me. I tried to clear secondary calendar created using Google API,
 with the same result as you had (Cannot clear primary calendar.)

Answer (score 2):

Just saw the reason - silly me. The documentation clearly states :

> Clears a primary calendar. This operation deletes all events associated with the primary calendar of an account.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear

If you want to clear all events from the **secondary** calendar, you will have to loop through all of them and delete one by one.

If you really want to clear all events from the **primary** calendar, you need to pass 'primary' as a parameter.